# Update .pdf field font color based on field text value

Tags: forms

I have a form that is test results. I want the font color for a field to change to red if the value FAIL is selected (it's a dropdown where they select pass or fail)  My guess is that I need to add some "if then" code that sets the font color in the ACTIONS tab of the properties. I am new to creating .pdf forms, so am at a loss. e.g. if Field.value ="FAIL" then ...?  any coaching is appreciated! Thanks!

What did I try?  I have stared like an idiot at the Actions tab in the properties for the field.